# Having trouble with "float:left;" while doing tic-tac-toe lines?

Tags: html, css

Help me please. I have a problem with the codes inside div.row{} I think I used wrong selector, and I couldn't solve it.

I think I should get the first child in div class:"row" part. So the first side in every row will be floated left, and other elements in the row will come after it.
I mean I wanted to get the first childs in every row, thats .top left, .middle left, and bottom left, but I xou

```css
body {
    padding: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
div.row{
    float: left;  
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    clear: both; /* after float, need to clear both */
}
.row {
    margin: 0 auto; /*to center it */
    width: 302px; /*extra 2 pics for the 2 vertical borders which im going to add */
}
.top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*all top classes will have bottom border */
}
.bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.right {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board"> <!--container for our game board-->
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <div class="row">
<!-- our 9 squares where players can place X or O, 3 squares for each row-->
            <div class="top left"></div>
            <div class="top middle"></div>
            <div class="top right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="middle left"></div>
            <div class="middle center"></div>
            <div class="middle right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="bottom left"></div>
            <div class="bottom middle"></div>
            <div class="bottom right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid which is tailored for this. Using floats for layout has never been a good solution, and in 2020 it's really nothing you want to do.

```css
.board { 
  background-color: #666;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.board > * { 
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Sir. Is there any other way to do this with display:inline-block tho?

Comment: There's lots of ways - floats, inline-blocks, flex, CSS tables... Yet CSS grid is clearly the technique of choice here.

Comment: Can I ask how to do this just with  float even if its not the right way to solve this issue?